# MediaPlayer not correctly releasing?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I'm implementing Simon Says in Android for a suite of Audiogames. The game is working fine but I can't seem to make the onPause and onStop methods work: with the current state of my code the MediaPlayers I use don't get released and if I add `mediaPlayer.reset()` or `mediaPlayer.stop()` the application crashes giving me this error in the Logcat

```
05-29 19:58:28.471 10205-10205/it.unimi.di.lim.audiogames E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: it.unimi.di.lim.audiogames, PID: 10205
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {it.unimi.di.lim.audiogames/it.unimi.di.lim.audiogames.Game2PlayActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4592)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4551)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4526)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:222)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1814)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
                                                                                at android.media.MediaPlayer._reset(Native Method)
                                                                                at android.media.MediaPlayer.reset(MediaPlayer.java:2052)
                                                                                at it.unimi.di.lim.audiogames.Game2PlayActivity$3.run(Game2PlayActivity.java:148)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:6036)
                                                                                at it.unimi.di.lim.audiogames.Game2PlayActivity.onPause(Game2PlayActivity.java:139)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:7034)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1340)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4578)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4551) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4526) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:222) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1814)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I imagine the error has to do with the fact that I'm using a Thread to synchronize the generation of sounds. Here follows the `createSequence` function

```
private void createSequence(final int i) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Random rand = new Random();
                for (int j = 0; j < i-1; j++) {
                    final int a = j;
                    try {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                playButton(temp.get(a));
                            }
                        });
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                final int seed = rand.nextInt(4);
                try {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            playButton(seed);
                            temp.add(seed);
                        }
                    });
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Button status = (Button) findViewById(R.id.game2_start_button);
                        status.setText(R.string.game2_repeat);
                        mWait = false;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.start();
    }
```

Which triggers the `playButton` method which is the one playing the actual sounds

```
private void playButton(int i) {
        Button mc_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.c_button);
        Button md_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.d_button);
        Button me_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.e_button);
        Button mf_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.f_button);
        switch(i) {
            case 0:
                mc_button.setBackgroundResource(R.color.game2_c_on);
                mCMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Game2PlayActivity.this, R.raw.c_sound);
                mCMediaPlayer.start();
                mCMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener);
                break;
            case 1:
                md_button.setBackgroundResource(R.color.game2_d_on);
                mDMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Game2PlayActivity.this, R.raw.d_sound);
                mDMediaPlayer.start();
                mDMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener);
                break;
            case 2:
                me_button.setBackgroundResource(R.color.game2_e_on);
                mEMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Game2PlayActivity.this, R.raw.e_sound);
                mEMediaPlayer.start();
                mEMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener);
                break;
            case 3:
                mf_button.setBackgroundResource(R.color.game2_f_on);
                mFMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Game2PlayActivity.this, R.raw.f_sound);
                mFMediaPlayer.start();
                mFMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Here following is my current implementation of the `OnPause` method (the OnStop method is the same). This doesn't stop the sounds from being played when leaving the Activity

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(mCMediaPlayer != null) {
                    mCMediaPlayer.release();
                    mCMediaPlayer = null;
                }
                if(mDMediaPlayer != null) {
                    mDMediaPlayer.release();
                    mDMediaPlayer = null;
                }
                if(mEMediaPlayer != null) {
                    mEMediaPlayer.release();
                    mEMediaPlayer = null;
                }
                if(mFMediaPlayer != null) {
                    mFMediaPlayer.release();
                    mFMediaPlayer = null;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Thanks in advance to anyone that can point out what the problem is

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Follows the full Java and XML codes if it's of any help

Java

```
01001101 01000100, [29.05.17 20:11]
package it.unimi.di.lim.audiogames;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Game2PlayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int mScore = 0;
    private LinkedList<Integer> temp = new LinkedList<);
    private boolean mClickable = false;
    private boolean mWait = false;
    private int mChecking = 0;

    private MediaPlayer mCMediaPlayer;
    private MediaPlayer mDMediaPlayer;
    private MediaPlayer mEMediaPlayer;
    private MediaPlayer mFMediaPlayer;

    private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener mCompletionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            releaseMediaPlayer(mp);
        }
    };

    private void releaseMediaPlayer(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.release();
            Button mc_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.c_button);
            Button md_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.d_button);
            Button me_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.e_button);
            Button mf_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.f_button);
            if(mediaPlayer == mCMediaPlayer) {
                mc_button.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.game2_c_off));
            } else if (mediaPlayer == mDMediaPlayer) {
                md_button.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.game2_d_off));
            } else if (mediaPlayer == mEMediaPlayer) {
                me_button.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.game2_e_off));
            } else {
                mf_button.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.game2_f_off));
            }
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }

    private void playButton(int i) {
        Button mc_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.c_button);
        Button md_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.d_button);
        Button me_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.e_button);
        Button mf_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.f_button);
        switch(i) {
            case 0:
                mc_button.setBackgroundResource(R.color.game2_c_on);
                mCMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Game2PlayActivity.this, R.raw.c_sound);
                mCMediaPlayer.start();
                mCMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener);
                break;
            case 1:
                md_button.setBackgroundResource(R.color.game2_d_on);
                mDMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Game2PlayActivity.this, R.raw.d_sound);
                mDMediaPlayer.start();
                mDMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener);
                break;
            case 2:
                me_button.setBackgroundResource(R.color.game2_e_on);
                mEMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Game2PlayActivity.this, R.raw.e_sound);
                mEMediaPlayer.start();
                mEMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener);
                break;
            case 3:
                mf_button.setBackgroundResource(R.color.game2_f_on);
                mFMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Game2PlayActivity.this, R.raw.f_sound);
                mFMediaPlayer.start();
                mFMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void createSequence(final int i) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Random rand = new Random();
                for (int j = 0; j < i-1; j++) {
                    final int a = j;
                    try {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                playButton(temp.get(a));
                            }
                        });
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                final int seed = rand.nextInt(4);
                try {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            playButton(seed);
                            temp.add(seed);
                        }
                    });
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Button status = (Button) findViewById(R.id.game2_start_button);
                        status.setText(R.string.game2_repeat);
                        mWait = false;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(mCMediaPlayer != null) {
                    mCMediaPlayer.reset();
                    mCMediaPlayer.release();
                    mCMediaPlayer = null;
                }
                if(mDMediaPlayer != null) {
                    mDMediaPlayer.reset();
                    mDMediaPlayer.release();
                    mDMediaPlayer = null;
                }
                if(mEMediaPlayer != null) {
                    mEMediaPlayer.reset();
                    mEMediaPlayer.release();
                    mEMediaPlayer = null;
                }
                if(mFMediaPlayer != null) {
                    mFMediaPlayer.reset();
                    mFMediaPlayer.release();
                    mFMediaPlayer = null;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(mCMediaPlayer != null) {
                    mCMediaPlayer.reset();
                    mCMediaPlayer.release();
                    mCMediaPlayer = null;
                }
                if(mDMediaPlayer != null) {
                    mDMediaPlayer.reset();
                    mDMediaPlayer.release();
                    mDMediaPlayer = null;
                }
                if(mEMediaPlayer != null) {
                    mEMediaPlayer.reset();
                    mEMediaPlayer.release();
                    mEMediaPlayer = null;
                }
                if(mFMediaPlayer != null) {
                    mFMediaPlayer.reset();
                    mFMediaPlayer.release();
                    mFMediaPlayer = null;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game2_play);

        Button mc_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.c_button);
        Button md_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.d_button);
        Button me_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.e_button);
        Button mf_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.f_button);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            Window window = this.getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.game2Dark));
            window.setNavigationBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.game2Primary));
        }

        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.game2Primary)));

        mc_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mClickable && !mWait) {
                    playButton(0);
                    int check = temp.get(mChecking);
                    mChecking++;
                    if (check != 0) {
                        Intent gameOver = new Intent(Game2PlayActivity.this, Game2Activity.class);
                        gameOver.putExtra("score", mScore);
                        startActivity(gameOver);
                    }
                    if (temp.size() == mChecking) {
                        mScore++;
                        TextView score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.game2_score);
                        score.setText(Integer.toString(mScore));
                        mClickable = false;
                        mChecking = 0;
                        Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.game2_start_button);
                        start.setText(R.string.game2_start);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        md_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mClickable && !mWait) {
                    playButton(1);
                    int check = temp.get(mChecking);
                    mChecking++;
                    if (check != 1) {
                        Intent gameOver = new Intent(Game2PlayActivity.this, Game2Activity.class);
                        gameOver.putExtra("score", mScore);
                        startActivity(gameOver);
                    }
                    if (temp.size() == mChecking) {
                        mScore++;
                        TextView score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.game2_score);
                        score.setText(Integer.toString(mScore));
                        mClickable = false;
                        mChecking = 0;
                        Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.game2_start_button);
                        start.setText(R.string.game2_start);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        me_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mClickable && !mWait) {
                    playButton(2);
                    int check = temp.get(mChecking);
                    mChecking++;
                    if (check != 2) {
                        Intent gameOver = new Intent(Game2PlayActivity.this, Game2Activity.class);
                        gameOver.putExtra("score", mScore);
                        startActivity(gameOver);
                    }
                    if (temp.size() == mChecking) {
                        mScore++;
                        TextView score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.game2_score);
                        score.setText(Integer.toString(mScore));
                        mClickable = false;
                        mChecking = 0;
                        Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.game2_start_button);
                        start.setText(R.string.game2_start);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    mf_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mClickable && !mWait) {
                    playButton(3);
                    int check = temp.get(mChecking);
                    mChecking++;
                    if (check != 3) {
                        Intent gameOver = new Intent(Game2PlayActivity.this, Game2Activity.class);
                        gameOver.putExtra("score", mScore);
                        startActivity(gameOver);
                    }
                    if (temp.size() == mChecking) {
                        mScore++;
                        TextView score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.game2_score);
                        score.setText(Integer.toString(mScore));
                        mClickable = false;
                        mChecking = 0;
                        Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.game2_start_button);
                        start.setText(R.string.game2_start);
                    }
                }
            }
        });


        Button start_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.game2_start_button);
        start_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!mClickable && !mWait) {
                    mWait = true;
                    mClickable = true;
                    createSequence(mScore+1);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Game1PlayActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/game2_score"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/game2_score"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.2"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/game2_start_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/game2_start"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="64dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/c_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/game2_c_off"
            android:layout_margin="16dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/d_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/game2_d_off"
            android:layout_margin="16dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/e_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/game2_e_off"
            android:layout_margin="16dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/f_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/game2_f_off"
            android:layout_margin="16dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Full project (might be buggy): https://www.mediafire.com/?hukauj1waef7va1

Answer (score 0):

Do not call

```
mDMediaPlayer.reset();
```

before

```
mDMediaPlayer.release();
```

because method `reset()` resets the MediaPlayer to its uninitialized state.

Even better check state of MediaPlayer in onPause() method, because you can get a "Races" with your callback `mCompletionListener`

Comment: Yeah apologize that was a failed attempt that remained in the code. Not sure what you mean with the race condition? Should that not be a problem since I run the codes only if the mediaPlayer is not null? Thanks for the feedback man

Comment: Yes you right, I did not pay attention to 'mediaPlayer = null'.

Comment: But you also need synchronized block in both places, or ReentrantLock block